# File input dialog opening very slowly in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload, input

I have simple input for uploading files and it only accepts `.class` files:

```
<input type="file" accept=".class">
```

Problem is that accept property (`accept=".class"`) causes dialog to open very slowly in Chrome, it sometimes takes even up to 10 seconds, but it works perfectly in Mozilla Firefox and Internet Explorer. I am using latest version of Chrome - `53.0.2785.116 m (64-bit)`. I find this really silly because other extensions work perfectly in Chrome as well. I have read other questions with similar problems, some of them suggested that adding `name` property may fix the problem, but it doesn't help in this case. Problem is really easy to reproduce, you only need the line of code I provided.

Edit:

Google published an update today - `53.0.2785.143` and it seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem. Fine on Firefox, really slow on Chrome....

Comment: Same thing here. Anyone find a bug link? Seems like a regression in 53.0.2785.116

Comment: I get slowness anytime a click is simulated via JS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known regression bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638874&q=component%3ABlink%3EForms%3EFile%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) in Chrome version `52.0.2743.116`.

The temporary workaround is use mime type and be explicit (no wildcards).  Ex replace:

`<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*">`

with:

`<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/gif, image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp, image/webp">`

To solve your specific problem this should work:

`<input type="file" accept="application/java-vm">` per the [mime types list](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

Comment: Thanks you a lot for answering! What would be a workaround for `.class` extension?

Comment: Great, thanks. By the way, Google published an update for Chrome today, I downloaded it few minutes ago and it seems to have fixed the problem, the code I provided in my question now works as intended - there's no delay. https://googlechromereleases.blogspot.rs/2016/09/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_29.html