# Input type file has delay to open when use accept .xml

Tags: html, google-chrome

In Google Chrome when i have some input type file and i set the attribute `accept=".xml"` the browser has a delay to open the explorer. But when i set other extension it doesn't happen.

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<input type="file" accept=".xml">
<input type="file" accept=".pdf">
```

Comment: I've converted your Plunker demo into a Stack Snippet. On a different note: I'm not seeing any difference in times between the XML file picker and the PDF file picker in your example in Chrome on Windows. Which browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Using Chrome both versions do have a slightly noticable delay for me. Oh yeah, using macOS here.

Comment: Yes, confirmed... A delay in Chrome on Mac OSX.

Comment: I'm using windows 10. Chrome's version is 54.0.2840.71. But i try in Ubuntu and the same thing happens.

Comment: Windows 7 - version 54.0.2840.71 m. Works fine for me
Could be similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772671/file-input-dialog-opening-very-slowly-in-google-chrome#comment66840730_39772671